# Iterate a data frame containing lists of column numbers, of different lengths, with a function in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame (df) of survey responses about human values with 57 columns/variables of numerical/scale responses. Each column belongs to one of ten categories, and they're not in contiguous groups.

I have a second dataframe (scoretable) that associates the categories with the column numbers for the variables; the lists of column numbers are all different lengths:

```
scoretable <- data.frame(
     valuename = 
     c("Conformity","Tradition","Benevolence","Universalism","Self- 
     Direction","Stimulation","Hedonism","Achievement","Power","Security"),
     valuevars = I(list(c(11,20,40,47), # Conformity
                        c(18,32,36,44,51), # Tradition
                        c(33,45,49,52,54), # Benevolence
                        c(1,17,24,26,29,30,35,38), # Universalism
                        c(5,16,31,41,53), # Self-Direction
                        c(9,25,37), # Stimulation
                        c(4,50,57), # Hedonism
                        c(34,39,43,55), # Achievement
                        c(3,12,27,46), # Power
                        c(8,13,15,22,56))), # Security
     stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I would like to iterate through scoretable with a function, valuescore, that calculates the mean and sd of all responses in that group of columns in data frame df and write the result to a third table of results:

```
valuescore = function(df,scoretable,valueresults){
    valuename = scoretable[,1]
    set <- df[,scoretable[,2]]
    setmeans <- colMeans(set,na.rm=TRUE)
    valuemean <- mean(setmeans)
    setvars <- apply(set, 2, var)
    valuesd <-sqrt(mean(setvars))
    rbind(valueresults,c(valuename, valuemean, valuesd))
}

a <- nrow(scoretable)
for(i in 1:a){
    valuescore(df,scoretable[i,],valueresults)
}
```

I am very new to R and programming in general (this is my first question here), and I'm struggling to determine how to pass list variables to functions and/or as address ranges for data frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's create an example data.frame:

```
df <- replicate(57, rnorm(10, 50, 20)) %>% as.data.frame()
```

Let's prepare the table result format:

```
valueresults <- data.frame(
  name = scoretable$valuename, 
  mean = 0
)
```

Now, a loop on the values of scoretable, a mean calculation by column and then the mean of the mean. It is brutal (first answer with `Map` is more elegant), but maybe it is easier to understand for a R beginnner.

```
for(v in 1:nrow(scoretable)){
  # let's suppose v = 1 "Conformity"
  columns_id <- scoretable$valuevars[[v]]

  # isolate columns that correspond to 'Conformity'
  temp_df    <- df[, columns_id]

  # mean of the values of these columns
  temp_means <- apply(temp_df, 2, mean)
  mean       <- mean(temp_means)

  # save result in the prepared table
  valueresults$mean[v] <- mean
}

> (valueresults)
             name     mean
1      Conformity 45.75407
2       Tradition 52.76935
3     Benevolence 50.81724
4    Universalism 51.04970
5  Self-Direction 55.43723
6     Stimulation 52.15962
7        Hedonism 53.17395
8     Achievement 47.77570
9           Power 52.61731
10       Security 54.07066
```

Comment: thanks for working with the pieces I already had in place; as you say, the other solution with 'Map' is elegant but this is more immediately accessible to me. Seeing both is valuable. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using `Map` to apply a function to the list `scoretable[, 2]`.

First I will create a test `df`.

```
set.seed(1234)
m <- 100
n <- 57
df <- matrix(sample(10, m*n, TRUE), nrow = m, ncol = n)
df <- as.data.frame(df)
```

And now the function `valuescore`.

```
valuescore <- function(DF, scores){
  f <- function(inx) mean(as.matrix(DF[, inx]), na.rm = TRUE)
  res <- Map(f, scores[, 2])
  names(res) <- scores[[1]]
  res
}

valuescore(df, scoretable)
#$Conformity
#[1] 5.5225
#
#$Tradition
#[1] 5.626
#
#$Benevolence
#[1] 5.548
#
#$Universalism
#[1] 5.36125
#
#$`Self-Direction`
#[1] 5.494
#
#$Stimulation
#[1] 5.643333
#
#$Hedonism
#[1] 5.546667
#
#$Achievement
#[1] 5.3175
#
#$Power
#[1] 5.41
#
#$Security
#[1] 5.54
```

Comment: Thanks, this is quite elegant, and helps me see how functions fit inside functions to break down the process more effectively. The second answer is more immediately understandable to me but it's really helpful to see two approaches.